# Why does enabling WMM on a WiFi router cause increase in latency?

Tags: router, ping, wifi-configuration, latency, qos

With only a single device connected to a WiFi router, enabling WMM (WiFi Multimedia) increases the latency by 80-90%.  Overall throughput increases significantly, however.

Why does enabling WMM increase the latency, especially since only a single device is connected to the router?

Answer (score 2):

The culprit may be Power Save Certification.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Multimedia_Extensions) :

```
The underlying concept of WMM PowerSave is that the station (STA)
triggers the release of buffered data from the access point (AP) by 
sending an uplink data frame. Upon receipt of such a data (trigger)
frame the AP releases previously buffered data stored in each of 
its queues.
```

The AP would thus be delaying packets until "instructed" to release them.